# If $\{u_n\} \to u$ and $\{v_n\} \to v$. Show that $\{\rho(u_n, v_n)\} \to \rho(u,v)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

Let $(X,\rho)$ to be a metric space in which $\{u_n\} \to u$ and $\{v_n\} \to v$. Show that $\{\rho(u_n, v_n)\} \to \rho(u,v)$

**Proof:**

Suppose $\{u_n\} \to u$ and $\{v_n\} \to v$. This means that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \rho(u_n,u) = 0 \text{ and } 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \rho(v_n,v) = 0.$$
Then, by the triangle inequality, we have
$$\rho(u,v) \leq \rho(u,u_n) + \rho(u_n,v) \leq \rho(u,u_n) + \rho(u_n,v_n) + \rho(v_n,v).$$
Letting $n$ approach infinity, we have that 
$$\rho(u,v) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \rho(u_n,v_n).$$
I was wondering if it is true that since $\{u_n\} \to u$ and $\{v_n\} \to v$, then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \rho(u_n,v_n) = \rho(u,v),$$
so that 
$$\rho(u,v) \leq \rho(u,v),$$
which completes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea. Your first inequality is equivalent to $$\rho(u,v)-\rho(u_n,v_n)\leqslant \rho(u,u_n)+\rho(v_n,v). $$
Applying the triangle inequality to $\rho(u_n,v_n)$ in a similar way yields
$$\rho(u_n,v_n)-\rho(u,v)\leqslant \rho(u,u_n)+\rho(v_n,v).$$
Together, these give $$|\rho(u_n,v_n)-\rho(u,v)|\leqslant \rho(u,u_n)+\rho(v_n,v),$$ and the result follows from convergence of $u_n$ and $v_n$.